# Java 8 list manipulation

Tags: java-8

I'm trying to do some basic map/filter operations on a list in a `ListChangeListener.onChanged(Change<? extends Place>)` method and I can get it working using the old-fashioned "iterate and do some ifs" way, but I wanted to try to write it using the `stream()` method from java 8. The commented part doesn't give the same result though, it fails to filter out the categories correctly (and yes, I have a working implementation of `equals(Object)` for `Category`

```
for (Place p : change.getAddedSubList()) {
    if (!categories.contains(p.getCategory())) {
        categories.add(p.getCategory());
    }
}
// List<Category> addedCategories = change.getAddedSubList().stream()
// 　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　.map(Place::getCategory)
//　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　.filter((c) -> { return !categories.contains(c); })
//  　                                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
//　categories.addAll(addedCategories);
```

Comment: Seems likely you'd prefer categories to be a Set, rather than a List.

Comment: not really, I thought about it, but since I want to add the collection as the item list to a listview, using a set only creates more hassle, as ListView.setItems() takes an ObservableList, not a set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because in the first version, once you have added a category to the list, a subsequent occurrence of this category isn't added a second time: you have already added it to the list. The second version doesn't do the same thing. So you need to make sure categories are unique in the stream:

```
change.getAddedSubList().stream()
      .map(Place::getCategory)
      .distinct()
      .filter(c -> !categories.contains(c))
      .forEachOrdered(c ->　categories.add(c));
```

Note that you also don't need to collect to a temporary list.

Comment: Note this this will produce unexpected results if somebody changes `stream()` to `parallelStream()`

Comment: Generally, you should use `forEachOrdered` if the order ought to be retained. And as far as I understood, retaining the order is the motivation for using a `List` rather than a `Set`.

Comment: @Holger agreed. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Duplicates in you stream may lead to duplicates in the categories list, when they are not contained in the categories list beforehand, since the filter method is applied for all items, before one of them is inserted.

One solution would be to insert a call to `.distinct()` in your Stream, another way to collect via `Collectors.toSet()`.